# BigQuery sum counts from start of year to date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sum

I Have a table (`TEST_TABLE`) which gives me the `HEADCOUNT` on the last day of each month (`LAST_DAY_MONTH`) for all individual companies (`COMPANNY`)

an example for 1 company:

| LAST_DAY_MONTH | COMPANNY | HEADCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-31 | x1 | 20 |
| 2023-02-28 | x1 | 22 |
| 2023-03-31 | x1 | 21 |
| 2023-04-30 | x1 | 27 |

Is there a possibility to create a new table with a summed headcount to date?

i.e

| LAST_DAY_MONTH | COMPANNY | HEADCOUNT_TO_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-31 | x1 | 20 |
| 2023-02-28 | x1 | 42 |
| 2023-03-31 | x1 | 63 |
| 2023-04-30 | x1 | 90 |

I allready tried

```
SELECT 
LAST_DAY_MONTH,
COMPANY_NAME,
SUM(CASE WHEN LAST_DAY_MONTH BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(LAST_DAY_MONTH, year) AND LAST_DAY_MONTH THEN HEADCOUNT END)
FROM `TEST_TABLE`
GROUP BY 1,2
```

But this just gives the headcount of each month

**EDIT:**
I ony want to sum headcounts from the same year so if I would look at the row of 2022-12-31, the `HEADCOUNT_TO_DATE` should be the sum of all 12 months of 2022.

On 2023-01-31 it shoud then only sum the headcount of the first month of 2023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the answer of Asi Salo pointed me in the right direction:

```
SELECT 
LAST_DAY_MONTH,
COMPANY_NAME,
SUM(HEADCOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY COMPANY_NAME, EXTRACT(year FROM LAST_DAY_MONTH) ORDER BY EXTRACT(month FROM LAST_DAY_MONTH)) AS HEADCOUNT_TO_DATE
FROM `TEST_TABLE`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function to calculate the running sum of the `headcount` for each company up to the current row.

```
SELECT
    LAST_DAY_MONTH,
    COMPANY_NAME,
    SUM(HEADCOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY COMPANY_NAME ORDER BY LAST_DAY_MONTH) AS HEADCOUNT_TO_DATE
FROM
    TEST_TABLE;
```

For the same year only you can do:

```
SELECT
    LAST_DAY_MONTH,
    COMPANY_NAME,
    SUM(HEADCOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY COMPANY_NAME, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM LAST_DAY_MONTH) ORDER BY LAST_DAY_MONTH) AS HEADCOUNT_TO_DATE
FROM
    TEST_TABLE;
```

Comment: This allready helps me a great way thanks!! But I only want to do this for data from the same year. So if I at the row of 2022-12-31 it would have summed all data from 2022 andd this data should not be added to 2023. 

so on 2023-01-31 it should start wiith only 1 month again. Is this also possible?